# Swap Adjacent nodes in a Linked List Only by Manipulating pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, swap

I am trying to swap the adjacent nodes of a linked list i.e.

1->2->3->4->5 becomes 2->1->4->3->5

My function is:

```
node * swapper(node * &head)
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) return head;

    node * t = head;
    head= head->next;
    head->next = t;
    t->next = head->next;

    node *previous = head->next->next, *current = previous->next;

    while (current!=NULL&&previous!=NULL)
    {
        node * t1 = current,*t2=previous;
        current->next = previous;
        previous->next = t1->next;
        previous = t1->next;
        current = previous->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

I know it can be done by swapping values but I have to do it in Constant space and without swapping the values.

I can't find why my function is not working.

Comment: This is not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), thus it is even more difficult for others to find out why it is not working. A good start would be if you tell us what is wrong with it. Are there compile/runtime errors? Does it run but not resulting in the expected output?

Comment: My recommendation is that you perform the algorithm on paper first. Draw each node as a box, the links (pointers) as labeled arrows, and try to figure out how to do it on the paper first. Then when you have something that you think will work, transfer the algorithm to code. And if the code doesn't work as expected, run in a debugger and step through the code line by line while keeping track of all pointers and what they point to (writing down on paper can help here too).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I can notice is that you need to swap those two lines:

```
head->next = t;
t->next = head->next;
```

because you are saying head->next = t so you are losing the connection to the rest of the linked list.

Also, inside the loop. There are several mistakes:
1- You're changing the next of current before obtaining it in previous, which means you're losing the link (like above)
2- You're not connecting them to the nodes that are before them.

Answer (score 1):

My five cents.:)

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how to write a recursive function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *head;

void push_front( node * &head, int x )
{
    head = new node { x, head };
}

void display( node *head )
{
    for ( node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        std::cout << current->data << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

node * swapper( node * &head )
{
    if ( head && head->next )
    {
        node *tmp = std::exchange(head, head->next );
        std::exchange( tmp->next, std::exchange( tmp->next->next, tmp ) );
        swapper( head->next->next );
    }

    return head;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; ) push_front( head, --i );

    display( head );

    display( swapper( head ) );
}
```

The program output is the following

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6 9 8
```

Take into account that not all compilers support function `std::exchange`. So you will need to write it yourself.:)

If to write the main the following way

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; ) push_front( head, --i );

    display( head );

    for ( node **current = &head; *current && ( *current )->next; current = &( *current )->next )
    {
        swapper( *current ); 
    }

    display( head );
}
```

then the following interesting output can be obtained.:)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9 8 6 4 2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
node * swapper(node * &head)
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) return head;

    node * t = head;
    head= head->next;

    t->next = head->next;
    head->next = t;

    node *previous = head->next->next, *current,*parent=head->next;

    while (previous&&(current = previous->next))
    {
        node * t1 = current,*t2=previous;
        previous->next = t1->next;
        current->next = previous;
        parent->next= current;

        previous = t2->next;
        //current = previous->next;
        parent=t2;
    }

    return head;
}
```